# How to keep values in Entry Widget after I wrote them for furthers lookback

Tags: python, tkinter, global-variables, tkinter-entry

I need to pick up some inputs values from an entry in a window but every time I come back to the window I need the values to be kept in the entry widget. I wrote a code like this:

```
class Mainwindows:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.mainframe = LabelFrame(self.master)
        self.sinputbutton = Button(self.mainframe, text="INPUT", command=self.openinput)
        self.sinputbutton.pack()

    def openinput(self):
        self.inputwindow = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Sinput(self.inputwindow)

class Sinput:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.inputframe = Frame(self.master)
        self.stuffinput = DoubleVar()
        self.stuffinput = Entry(self.inputframe, textvariable=self.stuffinput)
        self.stuffinput.pack()
        self.okbutton = Button(self.inputframe, text="Ok", command=self.inputok)
        self.soilbutton.pack(side="right", padx=5, pady=10)
        self.inputframe.pack()

    def inputok(self):
        global f
        f = self.stuffinput.get()
        self.master.destroy()
```

So I put the input into the entry and then I push the okbutton, at this point the variable f is stored and the input window closes, but if I manage to return to the input window the value happens to be 0, I need it to be kept as the value I wrote at first!

UPDATED CODE

```
import tkinter as tk

class Mainwindows:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.mainframe = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.mainframe.pack()

    # Create the variable in the main class
        self.inputVar1 = tk.DoubleVar()
        self.inputVar2 = tk.DoubleVar()


        self.sinputbutton = tk.Button(self.mainframe, text="INPUT", command=self.openinput)
        self.sinputbutton.pack()

    # Temp button to display value
        self.displaybutton = tk.Button(self.mainframe, text="Display", command=self.display)
        self.displaybutton.pack()

    def openinput(self):
        self.inputwindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)

    # Pass an instance of the DoubleVar into Sinput class
        self.app = Sinput(self.inputwindow, self.inputVar1, self.inputVar2)

# Temp function to show value
    def display(self):
        print(self.inputVar.get())

class Sinput:
    def __init__(self, master, var):
        self.master = master
        self.var = var

        self.inputframe = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.inputframe.pack()

        self.stuffinput = tk.Entry(self.inputframe, textvariable=self.var)
        self.stuffinput.pack()

        self.okbutton = tk.Button(self.inputframe, text="Ok", command=self.inputok)
    self.okbutton.pack(side="right", padx=5, pady=10)

    def inputok(self):
        self.master.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Mainwindows(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

As before I need to store the variables created by typing them into the two entrywidgets located in the input window because I'll need those values later and also need to show the values into the input window if I decide to come back for a further look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem you're having is that you destroy the window and then create a new one with each button click. In the below example I have the `DoubleVar` in the main class. This way it's not being destroyed each time. However each time a new window is created it will use the same `DoubleVar` therefore each Entry widget will display the current value it holds.

Now although you can use global on the `DoubleVar` to use it between classes. When using classes I prefer to stay away from it. To do this without global you can just pass in the variable.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Mainwindows:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.mainframe = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.mainframe.pack()

        # Create the variable in the main class
        self.inputVar = tk.DoubleVar()

        self.sinputbutton = tk.Button(self.mainframe, text="INPUT", command=self.openinput)
        self.sinputbutton.pack()

        # Temp button to display value
        self.displaybutton = tk.Button(self.mainframe, text="Display", command=self.display)
        self.displaybutton.pack()

    def openinput(self):
        self.inputwindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)

        # Pass an instance of the DoubleVar into Sinput class
        self.app = Sinput(self.inputwindow, self.inputVar)

    # Temp function to show value
    def display(self):
        print(self.inputVar.get())

class Sinput:
    def __init__(self, master, var):
        self.master = master
        self.var = var

        self.inputframe = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.inputframe.pack()

        self.stuffinput = tk.Entry(self.inputframe, textvariable=self.var)
        self.stuffinput.pack()

        self.okbutton = tk.Button(self.inputframe, text="Ok", command=self.inputok)
        self.okbutton.pack(side="right", padx=5, pady=10)

    def inputok(self):
        self.master.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Mainwindows(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

As a side note you can also look towards `tkinter.simpledialog.askstring` if you want a message box to get user input and return the value instead of creating your own.

Comment: I tried like you suggested by changing `DoubleVar` to `StringVar`, as a result it stores the variable as a string and I think  I need a float variable for the script I need to run using the inputs I'm trying to put in (but that's not my problem right now).The main problem remains unsolved: even with`StringVar`if I write for example 22.5 in the EntryWidged and then I push the okbutton, it creates a variable called f=22.5 (and it's ok I need that to be done) but when I come back to the Input window (think about I forgot what I wrote before and need to check) it shows like if I've wrote nothing!

Comment: Ah I see, it seems I didn't understand your question properly. I'll get to updating my answer. But as for why it shows nothing is because you `destroy` the window. And when you press the button it creates a completely new one.

Comment: I tried to make my code be like your last update and it works for one variable but let's suppose I got multiple variables (and unfortunately I do) I tried to create multiple variables in the Main Class and then to give an istance like `self.app = Sinput(self.inputwindow, self.inputVar1, self.inputVar2, etc)` that's the only variation I made to your suggestion code but it doesn't work, the window doesn't show nothing at all what did I miss?

Comment: Could you add the updated code to your question (not change the original, add new code) otherwise I have no clue without seeing what you've changed. Also, if you have a lot of variables you can add them to a list and only pass the list in.

Comment: You need to add additional arguments to the init function for your Sinput class. That is if you want to use each of those in the same window.